# js use async as default in import

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Is it possible to have an import automatically be async.

Right now I have to do this:

main.js

```
import './import.js'
```

import.js

```
(async() => {
    const result = await fetch(...); 
    console.log(result);
})();
```

But I would rather have it without the self invoking function:

import.js

```
    const result = await fetch(...); 
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with imports? Sounds like you want to use `async`/`await` on the *module* level, regardless of what is im- or exported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript await by default instead of manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147316/javascript-await-by-default-instead-of-manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. `await` must always be inside of an `async` block.

See https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions

Comment: No longer true as of ECMAScript 2022.